# How can my program ignore touchesMoved when my finger leaves the subview?

Tags: ios, xcode

I currently have a program with the a viewcontroller and a subview. The subview has all of the touch logic located in it. When I slide my finger outside of the subview, the touchesMoved method doesn't stop processing my touch info. I know that the touchesMoved method doesn't end until i lift my finger off of the screen,but there has got to be a way to get my program to ignore the touches after my finger leaves the subview. Anyone know of any such methods that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:yourSubview];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(yourSubview.frame, location))
    {
        //process touch
    }
    else
    {
        //touch is outside of the subview
    }
}
```